# Custom post type permalink remove

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to remove the custom post type name of the permalink.

I created a custom post type like this:

```
    add_action( 'init', 'register_projects' );
    function register_projects() {
        register_post_type( 'proyectos_post',
            array(
                'labels' => array(
                    'name' => __( 'Proyectos' )
                ),
                'public' => true,
                'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor'),
                'hierarchical' => true,
                'menu_position' => 4
            )
        );
    }
```

The problem is that when I enter to a post, the url gets: www.myweb.com/proyectos_post/mypost

I want it to be like this:
www.myweb.com/mypost

Is it possible to do it without external plugins?

Comment: Check out 'rewirte' section in [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type). You can specify what will be the rewrite slug of your custom post type, so you could change it to `myweb.com/whatever_slug_i_want/mypost`. If you really want to completely remove the rewrite slug from URL, I believe you will need to alter your permalinks structure in WP-Admin, but this will affect all your post types.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'custom-post-name', 'with_front' => FALSE)